# Converting double to char in csv file

Tags: java, string, csv

I have a problem to convert a String number into a char character/csv file:

1. Using the Filwriter for reading a csv file:

FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("features.csv");

2. Header of my csv file is:

   ```
   writer.append("EnergieMagnXYZ");
   writer.append(',');
   writer.append("label");
   writer.append('\n');
   ```
3. Appending rows of data by:

   ```
   writer.append(Double.toString(energie));
   writer.append(',');
   writer.append(label);
   ```
4. Creating label values by:

   String label = " ";

   ```
   if(tt[i] > 600){
       label = "1";
   }else if(tt[i] < 600){
       label = "0";    
   }
   ```

**The values of my Energie double array tt[i] are:**

2139.0882022271244

2334.38651422678

2329.342679013897

2286.6136318937574

**But when I create my csv file my output will be like this:**

EnergieMagnXYZ,label

21.390.882.022.271.200,00

233.438.651.422.678,00

2.329.342.679.013.890,00

22.866.136.318.937.500,00

**But I want an output like this in my created csv file (in the case label is 0):**

EnergieMagnXYZ,label

2139.0882022271244,0

2334.38651422678,0

2329.342679013897,0

2286.6136318937574,0

**Be careful:**

2139.0882022271244,0

is not single number but 2139.0882022271244 and 0 are seperated fields. So my rows consist of a double value and label in a number format (0 or 1). Moreover the dots in my double value are really important for the further use.

What do I need to change to get an output like this?

Comment: What is the actual value of your Energie? Is it < 3000 or > 21e15? Also, are you sure what you are getting is `.200,00`? I think it might be `.200,0,0`.

Comment: hello. the actual value is 2139.0882022271244. sorry it may be confusing. the 0 after the comma  doesnt belong to the actual value of 2139.0882022271244, its a single value

Comment: No, I was asking about your current output. Does it really print `.200,00`?

Comment: Yes! When I have created the csv file and look at the first row the output will be .200,00. As I mentionded what I want is 2139.0882022271244,0

Comment: I don't think this output comes from this part of the code. Perhaps there is something else that writes to your writer? Perhaps some other writer writing to the file?

Comment: it strange because when I do the following: writer.append(','); writer.append(label); writer.append(','); writer.append('\n'); then output will be 2139.0882022271244,0, correctly but with a comma at the end

Comment: Sorry, you'll have to edit your question and add all the relevant code. What is `writer`, where is it initialized, everything else that uses the same writer, etc.

Comment: I have used the Filewriter.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you are looking for:

```
NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getInstance();
nf.setGroupingUsed(false); // remove the dots grouping each 3 digits
nf.setMaximumFractionDigits(0); // remove the fraction digits
String formatedEnergie = nf.format(Energie));
```

Now you print formatedEnergie instead of Energie like the following.

```
NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getInstance();
nf.setGroupingUsed(false); // remove the dots grouping each 3 digits
nf.setMaximumFractionDigits(13); // remove the fraction digits
String formatedEnergie = nf.format(Double.toString(energie)));
writer.append(formatedEnergie);
writer.append(',');
writer.append(label);
```

You will get the value 
2286.6136318937574

If that's not exactly what you want, play a little with the [NumberFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html) API until you get the output you are looking for.

Comment: thank you for answer. its not exactly what I wanted.probably my described intention hasnt been clear. the expression 21.390.882.022.271.200,0  are two seperated fields in my csv file the 0 after the comma doesnt belong to the number  21.390.882.022.271.200. so i have two fields **21.390.882.022.271.200 (field energie value)**,**0(field label)**

Comment: In that case, change the line of the code I wrote above from :
nf.setMaximumFractionDigits(0);
to
nf.setMaximumFractionDigits(13);

that will give you 13 fraction digits.

So, if your Energie is a double 2139.0882022271244, you will have exactly that.

Comment: thank you so much! its almost working. but when I use **String formatedEnergie = nf.format(Double.toString(energie)))** I'll get an exception "Cannot format given Object as a Number" I have edited the code line in **String formatedEnergie = nf.format(energie)**. Well, the output will be like this: **2139,0882022271244**. Instead of dots I'll get commas. Is there a way to get dots instead of commas?